# Загрузка js на странице с https

Tags: javascript, ssl, https

Возникла проблема с загрузкой javascript на странице с https. Если загружать скрипт с **http://**, то вылезет ошибка `Mixed Content: The page at 'http://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` А если загружать скрипт с **https://**, то он вообще работать не будет. Как это исправить?

Comment: @Какую ошибку он выдает ?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, а вы в скайп напишите, чтобы они скрипт исправили этот. Внутри него идет обращение по протоколу http принудительно.

Comment: заменить `http` на `https` в адресе. У скайпа доступны оба протокола